# How to choose a color on a palette to change part of an image?

Tags: html, css, web

I don't even know where to begin or what codes will be needed.

I'm trying to build a website that allows the user to change a certain part of an image's color. Just like a coloring book page online, where someone can choose a color from the palette and it will allow them to click on that part of the image to change it to that color. Once they are done they can save the image to their computer.

Any help in the right direction would be incredible!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a transparent div over a div containing the image which is in absolute position of the div containing the image.

Then you can check some javascript plugin to get a color picker plugin.

With Javascript and for example jQuery, you can add some events on click on the color picker and then on click of the div which is hover the image to apply the picked color.

I hope this is clear for you, otherwise I can make a JSfiddle